# Calculating the volume of a solid of revolution obtained by rotating two parabolas

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to calculate the volume of a solid of revolution obtained by rotating two parabolas, $y=x^2-x-6$ and $y=-x^2+x+6$.

I want to use the formula: volume $=\pi \int_{a}^{b}(g^2(x)-f^2(x))dx$.

I already calculated $a,b = -2, +3$, which are intersections of the two parabolas.

However, I am not sure which function to put for $g^2$ and which to put for $f^2$. I know that the "upper" function should be $g(x)$, however, which one is upper in this case?

When using the latter function as $g(x)$ (because on the interval it has higher values), I get $0$ as a result of the integral. Not sure what to do now.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you graph the two functions to find out which of the two functions is lying outside the other one? Both functions describe parabolas.

Comment: @YNK I did that and I found out that the latter function has higher values on the interval (a,b). However, when I calculated the integral, I got $0+C$ as a result. Not sure what to do.

Comment: @YNK Is $\pi $ the volume?

Comment: You are getting zero because your formula is only valid in the case both $f$ and $g$ are non-negative (and $g\geq f$ in $(a,b)$). If you draw the graphs of your parabolas, you see that they are symmetric about the $x$ axis, so the required solid is the same as what you get when revolving just one parabola. So, your volume is simply $\pi\int_a^bg^2(x)dx$.

Comment: @Kostya_I Thanks.

Comment: You haven't specified an axis of rotation.

Comment: @B. Goddard Due to the symmetry, there are two different axes of rotations, one vertical $\left(x=0.5\right)$ and one horizontal  $\left(x-\rm{axis}\right)$.

Comment: @YNK  No, there are infinitely many possible axes of rotation.  Nothing stops us from rotating about $y=10$ or $x = -7$.  If he doesn't tell us, then none of the solutions are valid.

Comment: @B. Goddard Yes I agree with you. The axes of rotation , which I mentioned in my previous comment, were the simplest to work with. Besides, there was an answer from a user called Sam, which has been withdrawn, using one of the two axes I mentioned. I provided the solution for the other axis. The OP has accepted my answer without commenting. So we are still in the dark. I am sorry for trying to mislead you on this matter. It was unintentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Solid of Revolution]

As shown in Fig. 1, the area bounded by the two parabolae is symmetrical about the $x$-axis. This allows us to choose $x$-axis as the axis of rotation of the generated solid in question. Furthermore, instead of rotating both parabolae simultaneously through an angle of $\pi$, we can rotate one of them through an angle of $2\pi$. We opt for the parabola $y=-x^2+x+6$. Now, consider a yellow strip with height $y$ and width $dx$. Volume $dV$ generated by the strip when it is rotated by an angle $2\pi$ is given by
$$dV=\pi y^2 dx=\pi\left(-x^2+x+6\right)^2dx=\pi\left(x^4-2x^3-11x^2+12x+36\right)dx.$$
The integration that yields the total volume runs along $x$-axis from $x=-2$ to $x=+3$. Therefore, the total volume of the solid of revolution is,
$$V=\int dv=\pi\int^{+3}_{-2}\left(x^4-2x^3-11x^2+12x+36\right)dx,$$
$$V=\pi \left|\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^4}{2}-\frac{11x^3}{3}+6x^2+36x\right|^{+3 }_{-2}=\frac{625}{6}\pi.$$
I have included Fig. 2 to show you that it is also possible to find the required volume by considering a horizontal strip and running the integration in $y$ direction from $y=0$ to $y=6.25$ and finally multiplying the result of the integration by 2. In this instance the axis of rotation is the vertical line given by $x=0.5$.

I assume that you have find out why you got a solid of revolution with a zero volume in your attempt earlier. @Kostya_I has described the reason in her comment.